# Opencart module development - Inject javascript/html code in some pages

Tags: opencart

I'm a beginner on Opencart and just started developing a module for Opencart which it must inject some lines of javascript and html code in these pages:
- Cart Page
- Product Page
- Confirmation Order Page
- Register form page

The official documentation doesn't have informations about how can i do that, I've tried to find a good documentation about OpenCart but I didn't find anything.

I need help. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diggin necro topics;) :

The easiest way i think:

upload/catalog/view/theme/[themename]/template/product/product.tpl - here you can add your custom html for product page

[your theme name, you shouldnt overwrite default theme because it can cause damage after update]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you're trying to insert the HTML/JavaScript.

Doing things the *proper* way in OpenCart, you're limited to the column-left, column-right, content-top, and content-bottom positions.

The files you'll need to create are:

```
admin/controller/module/mymodule.php
admin/language/english/module/mymodule.php
admin/view/template/module/mymodule.tpl
catalog/controller/module/mymodule.php
catalog/language/module/mymodule.php
catalog/view/theme/default/module/mymodule.php
```

To learn how to do this the first time, it's easiest to replicate an existing stock OpenCart module (preferably a simple one, such as information). Once you've replicated it you'll need to go through each of those files and replace any references to "information" with "mymodule".

After that, if you've done it properly, you should be able to navigate to Admin > Extensions > Modules and see your module in there. Then install it, use the "Add module" button to position the module on all the relevant layouts, hit save and hey presto you have a working module on the front-end.

To modify the front-end output, just edit `catalog/view/theme/default/module/mymodule.php`

If you want to insert your HTML somewhere other than the 4 available positions OpenCart gives you, position your module in the content-bottom position and use JavaScript/jQuery to inject some HTML where you want.

If this is for your own personal website then as Pawel S suggested it would be easiest to simply modify the relevant view files (ie.  `catalog/view/theme/[themename]/template/product/product.tpl`), however if you're making a module which you plan to distribute then this should be a last resort.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is probably long dead by now, but if you're creating a module that needs to modify existing controllers, languages, models or views the correct tool to use is vQMod.

vQMod allows you to modify existing code on the fly using XML.

https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/